# Can you use "at dusk" in the meaning of "at the end"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

Can you use "at dusk" to describe something at its later or final stage?

E.g. Does "at the dusk of the 20th century" make any sense at all? If not, is there any expression that would convey this meaning?

Comment: It's a poetic analogy, and it makes sense to me. But I wouldn't use it in a scientific journal. (In that forum, simply say *at the end of the twentieth century*.)

Comment: Thanks Jason, that's all I was looking for. It's for a tweet actually, but wanted to double-check it.

Answer (score 3):

Although *dawn* is definitely used to refer to the onset or start of something, "the dawn of the twentieth century," I have never come across *dusk* being used in this way, despite "dawn to dusk" being a set phrase of opposites.

Google Books does contain a few examples, but they seem to be translations from German.

My preference would be for *twilight* (which is always associated with evening or the end of days, despite being equally valid in the morning) or something like *fading years* of the century.

That said, it's a poetic use of language which would not be misunderstood; but it is a **poetic** use of language.